# How to change the view my admin url is pointing to dynamically?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have some long running process during which I'd like to point all my admin url to some "a process is running, please come back later" template.

In my urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin_site.urls)),
```

I know I can create a view in which I can check whether my process is running, but I don't know how to use `include(admin_site.urls)` in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a MiddleWare. Something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LongProcessMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        running_long_process = True # some logic
        if running_long_process and request.get_full_path().startswith('/admin'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/temporary-disabled-message')
        return None
```

in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'myproject.middleware.LongProcessMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "include(admin_site.urls)" in your view.
In your urls.py file, check if your process is running and then add the right admin url.
like this :

```
from myapp import CheckIfProcessRunning

process = CheckIfProcessRunning()

if process :
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include('myapp.comebacklater')),
    )

else :
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include('myapp.myadminurl')),
    )
```